# Symfony2, get file type from request

Tags: file, symfony

I have a form in my template with a file input.

In my controller, i can retrieve my file with `$request->files->get('file');` but how can retrieve the type ?

Is there a way with Symfony2 ?

Comment: i think you can check the request "content-type" header

Comment: which for example is "application/pdf" for pdf or "application/json" for json etc. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` function of the `FileBag` class will return an [`UploadedFile`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) object (or throws a [`FileException`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/Exception/FileException.html) if there was an error.) You can get the MIME Type of the file with [the following method](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getMimeType):

```
$file = $request->files->get('file');
$type = $file->getMimeType();
```